# (Post/Redirect/Get pattern) Laravel layout variables don't work after redirect

Tags: layout, laravel, laravel-4, post-redirect-get

I'm using the [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern in my Laravel controllers to prevent duplicate form submission.

It works well when I don't use layouts or when my layouts don't use any variable. The problem is my layout uses a variable named `$title`. When I load the view and the layout without redirect it works well, the title set in the controller is passed to the layout, but after processing a form and redirecting to the same route which uses the same layout and the same controller method I get a **"Undefined variable: title"** error coming from my layout file.

Here is my code:

File: app/routes.php

```
Route::get('contact', array('as' => 'show.contact.form', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showContactForm'));
Route::post('contact', array('as' => 'send.contact.email', 'uses' => 'HomeController@sendContactEmail'));
```

File: app/controllers/HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function showContactForm()
    {
        $this->layout->title = 'Contact form';
        $this->layout->content = View::make('contact-form');
    }

    public function sendContactEmail()
    {
        $rules = ['email' => 'required|email', 'message' => 'required'];
        $input = Input::only(array_keys($rules));
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($validator->fails())
            return Redirect::back()->withInput($input)->withErrors($validator);

        // Code to send email omitted as is not relevant

        Redirect::back()->withSuccess('Message sent!');
    }
}
```

File: app/views/layouts/master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{{ $title }}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('body')
    </body>
</html>
```

File: app/views/contact-form.blade.php

```
@section('body')
    @if (Session::has('success'))
        <div class="success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>
    @endif

    {{
        Form::open(['route' => 'send.contact.email']),
        Form::email('email', null, ['placeholder' => 'E-mail']),
        Form::textarea('message', null, ['placeholder' => 'Message']),
        Form::submit(_('Send')),
        Form::close()
    }}
@stop
```

I don't understand why after redirecting the next line of code is ignored

```
$this->layout->title = 'Contact form';
```

I've tried with `Redirect::action('HomeController@sendContactEmail');` or `Redirect::route('show.contact.form');` but the result is the same.

**The controller in charge of rendering that view is exactly the same before the redirect than after the redirect, and it has no business logic at all, so why it only works on the first case but not in the second?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Redirect::back()->withSuccess('Message sent!');
```

should be

```
return Redirect::back()->withSuccess('Message sent!');
```

When `layout` attribute is set in a controller and method is not returning any response, controller try to render the `layout`. In your `sendContactEmail()` method both conditions fulfilled and controller tried to render layout before `$title` is set.

see `callAction()` in `Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\controller`.

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Controllers.Controller.html#93-127

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
return View::make('contact-form', array('title' => 'Contact Form'));
```

Instead of interacting with the layout directly?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect::back() creates a 302 using the referer value of the current HTTP request. I would start by comparing the initial form request to the redirect request to see if that yields any clues. You could also try...

```
Redirect::route('HomeController@showContactForm')->withInput()...
```

I know it's less dynamic but it will generate the URL rather then rely on the referer value in the HTTP header.